# How do you send rows of data to a table in report viewer?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, reportviewer

I'm using `VS 2013` and its report viewer. I want to make a report that is not limited to one sql statement or one use. One idea I had was to treat it like a `listview`. First get the data from `MySQL`, then read it one line at a time and send it to the table. But in report viewer it demands that I have a dataset/source. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be using textboxes since they don't "grow" or "shrink" according to the number of records. If I had to make an algorithm, it would be like this.

1. Query MySQL
2. While reading each line, send it to report viewer.
3. In report viewer, after printing the line/row. Append new row.
4. Go to next line
5. Repeat from #2 until end of line.

This is what I want generally. If somebody out there asks why I want to do this instead of using datasets, simply because I'm having a hard time finding a good tutorial that teaches how to bind datasources at runtime including the query. AND I really want this report to be dynamic. Also, for knowledge's sake.

Comment: By saying dynamic report, do you mean that the number of the columns will depend on the provided sql query? if yes, what algorithm would specify the location of each dynamically created column?

Comment: Not the columns. But the rows. I can specify a specific number of columns, but I don't have to use them all. I'll just skip the last few columns I don't need. I understand the limitations of what I'm asking, I know I can't have a "Mother-of-all-reports" to handle all the reports. But I do know some reports can have very similar formats, and only differ in the number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of report can be created very easily by using a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The following instruction will guide you in creating an [MS Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885185.aspx) that will have 3 columns (which will have their visibility depending on a parameter) and 10 rows.

This will provide you the basic concept. The DataSet then can be generated based on an SQL query irrelevant of the [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) that you will use.

This is a diagram of the basic components that will be used.

---

[image]

---

1. The DataSet and the Report file after their creation (in the Solution Explorer)
2. The DataSet containing a DataTable which will be used on the Report
3. The [Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338686%28v=nav.71%29.aspx) content
4. The columns of the DataSet that will be used on the report (in the Report Data)
5. The [List data region](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that will make the rows show one bellow the other

---

### Steps

Create a new Windows Forms Application.

[image]

[image]

In Solution Explorer, right click → Add → New item, from the window that will appear, select Data → DataSet, press Add.

[image]

[image]

Repeat the same, but this time add a Reporting → Report.

Double click on DataSet1.xsd from the Solution Explorer and add a new    DataTable there by right clicking on DataSet1 content → Add → DataTable.

[image]

Right click on the DataTable inside the DataSet and Add → Column.

[image]

Rename the name of the column to Column1 and create 2 other columns (Column2, Column3).

Double click on Report1.rdlc from the Solution Explorer so that it gets into the editor. Inside editor right click → insert Page header and then repeat for a Page footer.

[image]

Inside the Report Data window (shows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), right click on Datasets → Add Dataset. On the window that will appear there is a Data source ComboBox, change it to DataSet1 and press OK.

[image]

Right click on the middle section (body) of the report inside its editor → Insert → List. Shape it so that it will resemble the area shown on   the above diagram. You can also shape the height and the width of the header, the  body and the footer.

[image]

[image]

Drag and drop each of the 3 columns from the Report Data Window inside the List area.

[image]

Now, since we have the basic structure of the report, we will add the rules for the columns. First we will create the Parameter based on which, the columns will show or hide. Right click on Parameters inside the Report Data Window → Add parameter. From the window that  will appear, rename the Parameter as Parameter1, change its DataType to integer and press OK.

[image]

[image]

Right click on Column1 inside the List area → Text Box Properties. From the window that will appear, select Visibility → enable Show or hide based on an expression → click on fx button. On the new window, select Parameters inside the Category tree → double click on Parameter1 inside the Values. An expression like `=Parameters!Parameter1.Value` will show up, change it to `=Parameters!Parameter1.Value < 1` and press OK.

This expression will make the Column1 to hide when the value of the Parameter1 will be less than 1 and will show otherwise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Repeat the previous step for the other 2 columns by setting the following expressions, for column2 `=Parameters!Parameter1.Value < 2` and for column3 `=Parameters!Parameter1.Value < 3`

Double click on the Form1.vb from the Solution Explorer and drag and drop from the Toolbox Window the following controls on the form. A Reporting →  ReportViewer (without specifying a report for it), a Common Controls → Command Button, a ComboBox and a Label. Enter inside the code view by pressing F7 (works when the form is selected).

[image]

Replace the existing code with the following:

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class Form1

    Dim DataTable1 As New DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ConfigureControls()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        PreviewData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        DataTable1.Dispose()
        ReportViewer1.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PreviewData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PreviewData()
        DataTable1.Clear()

        Dim i As Integer
        'Fills the DataTable with test data (10 rows, 3 columns)'
        For i = 0 To 9
            DataTable1.Rows.Add(DataTable1.NewRow)
            DataTable1.Rows(i).Item("Column1") = "Row" & CStr(i + 1) & " Column1"
            DataTable1.Rows(i).Item("Column2") = "Row" & CStr(i + 1) & " Column2"
            DataTable1.Rows(i).Item("Column3") = "Row" & CStr(i + 1) & " Column3"
        Next

        Dim ReportDataSource1 As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", CType(DataTable1, DataTable))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WindowsApplication1.Report1.rdlc"
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter("Parameter1", Convert.ToByte(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource1)
        ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConfigureControls()
        Me.Size = New Size(575, 450)
        Me.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) / 2,
                                (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height) / 2)

        ReportViewer1.Location = New Point(12, 12)
        ReportViewer1.Size = New Size(535, 358)
        ReportViewer1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or
                               AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Top

        Button1.Location = New Point(459, 377)
        Button1.Size = New Size(88, 28)
        Button1.Text = "Preview"
        Button1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom

        ComboBox1.Location = New Point(365, 381)
        ComboBox1.Size = New Size(78, 21)
        ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"3", "2", "1"})
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        ComboBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom

        Label1.Location = New Point(232, 385)
        Label1.Size = New Size(131, 13)
        Label1.Text = "Hide columns greater than"
        Label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom
    End Sub

End Class
```

Run the code by pressing F5 and check its behavior when you change the ComboBox value and hit Preview.

[image: enter code here]

---

Comment: Hello. To be honest I actually figured this out a few hours before you posted. But this is really well done. Very detailed. Now I even have this as a guide if I forget next time. Thank you for your time. I'll upvote this.

Comment: A question about the visibility. Is there a way to hide succeeding rows containing similar data? Example: a clinic can have multiple doctors, and a doctor can have multiple patients. In sql i can query `order by doctorname`. But in the report i only want the name of each doctor to appear once. Can i use visibility to do this?

Comment: Check this solution http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/311878/Hide-Duplicate-value-in-table-ReportViewer